# Can the drunk's win condition be met even while he's still drunk?

Tags: werewolv.es

Let's say you're a Drunk Warlock, and the coven wins while you're still drunk. Is your personal win condition met? I assume logically what would happen is, the Drunk would sober up after the win and be like, "Oh cool, my side won, even though I was drunk through their whole struggle"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before they sober up, Drunks are not a specific role. (So a "Drunk Warlock" is not a thing).

Drunks are manually converted to another role by the game moderator when required to rebalance the game.

It would be unlikely for a drunk to still be drunk at the end of the game unless they died early, in which case they are not part of the winning faction.